# Use UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer without scrolling google map for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, uigesturerecognizer, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am working with google maps iOS sdk 1.8.1 and I want to use UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer from the left over the map. I already have the gesture working but I want to disable the scrolling on the map only when I am using the UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer. I tried to disable the scroll in the action method of the gesture with

```
myMapView.settings.scrollGestures = NO;
```

and also in

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

but it didn't work as i believe the map is the one receiving first the event, so is there a way to detect first the UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer before the google map gestures? I'll appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you implement on your delegate:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
  return NO;
}
```

You'll be able to disable multi-gesture recognition.